# Making border-image work with gradients

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, border

I'm working on a webapp that uses react.js and sass for styles (so all my style files are .scss). I have a textbox with the current style:

```
input[type=text] {
  text-align: center;
  font: inherit;
  border: 6px solid #999999;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #DDD;
  width: 223px;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  color: #7B8585;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
}
```

At some point, my app wants to change the border colour. This is what I have for that:

```
var borderStyle;
if (gradient) {
  borderStyle = {
    'borderImage': '-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #0083c5 0%, #0083c5 33%, #ec4a26 66%, #ec4a26 100%)',
  };
}
```

Later, the input component:

```
<input type="text" style={borderStyle} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Currently what I see is a white border with a tiny image of the red-blue gradient in each corner of the border. I've tried using `borderColor`, which doesn't work with gradients at all, apparently. Am I missing something obvious, or is it not possible to do a simple border gradient?

The desired result is a left-to-right gradient (so the left border is entirely blue, the right is entirely red, and the top and bottom borders feature the blue-to-red transition).

---

In response to Harry's answer, I changed to the following code:

```js
if (gradient) {
  borderStyle = {
    borderImage: 'linear-gradient(to right, #0083c5 0%, #0083c5 33%, #ec4a26 66%, #ec4a26 100%)',
    borderImageSlice: 1
  };
}
```

as specified in the [react docs for inline styles](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html).
However when I inspect the element, the `borderImageSlice` property I've defined is missing; only the `borderImage` one is there, and I still only have tiny gradients in the corners of the border.

Comment: How should the end output look like? For the current gradient supplied, the left edge (and left border) would be blue and it will change towards the right such that the right edge would be full red. Is that what you want? You are missing just one extra setting if that is the desired output.

Comment: You're on the right track, but your gradient syntax is wrong.

Comment: @HenrikAndersson: For a webkit specific linear gradient, the syntax is not wrong. It would work as-is.

Comment: Edited the main post to clarify my desired output; a left-to-right blue->red gradient. Also, this is running in Chrome, but would be good to support any browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a [`border-image-slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-slice) property also while applying the border. Doing this would give the exact output as you need.

I have added it via CSS itself in the below snippet (without the JS) but you should be able to adapt it :)

```css
input[type=text] {
  text-align: center;
  font: inherit;
  border: 6px solid #999999;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #DDD;
  width: 223px;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  color: #7B8585;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0083c5 0%, #0083c5 33%, #ec4a26 66%, #ec4a26 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

**Note:** I have also modified the gradient syntax to use the standard one so that it works in all browsers that support `border-image` property.

---

Below is a snippet which applies the border image when the text in the input box is changed.

```js
var ip = document.getElementById("inp");

ip.addEventListener("change", function() {
  this.style.borderImage = 'linear-gradient(to right, #0083c5 0%, #0083c5 33%, #ec4a26 66%, #ec4a26 100%)';
  this.style.borderImageSlice = '1';
});
```

```css
input[type=text] {
  text-align: center;
  font: inherit;
  border: 6px solid #999999;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #DDD;
  width: 223px;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  color: #7B8585;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp" />
```

---

It seems like ReactJS by default adds `px` as units to all numbers that are passed for inline styles and because of this the `border-image-slice: 1` is wrongly getting set as `border-image-slice: 1px`. As this property is a unitless property in CSS, it is not getting applied properly. The solution is to wrap this value within quotes and also add a semi-colon within the quotes (like in the below code sample):

```
var borderStyle = {
    borderImage: 'linear-gradient(to right, #0083c5 0%, #0083c5 33%, #ec4a26 66%, #ec4a26 100%)',
      borderImageSlice: '1;' // note the quotes and the semi-colon.
  };
```

Big credits for finding out this problem goes to [Henrik Andersson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/441387/henrik-andersson).

[JSBin Demo with ReactJS](http://jsbin.com/loquqibami/1)

Comment: If I put that into my style.scss sheet, it works fine. If I put that into my javascript style override, it doesn't. That's just weird...

Comment: @IronWaffleMan: Yes, that is weird. Unfortunately I don't know much about ReactJS or how it works. Would it be possible for you to show a demo somewhere? I can maybe help fixing it.

Comment: When I do an inspect of the element, it doesn't even include the border-image-slice property I've added. I'm using react's inline styles syntax as specified here (https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html), so I don't know what's wrong...

Comment: @IronWaffleMan: I've tried implementing the same with pure JS (have added it to the answer) and it seems to work fine. Maybe that's something wrong with ReactJS.

Comment: @IronWaffleMan: Can you try adding quotes around the `1` and see if it works. Its just a wild guess.

Comment: This works; http://jsbin.com/cowaxeyepa even without `border-image-slice` and `border-style`. Which leads me to believe that the gradient itself is iffy.

Comment: @Harry, that doesn't work. Henrik Andersson, as soon as I add 'webkit' to the style string it just goes default grey. Also, that demo appears as grey to me.

Comment: Check again, I messed it up. You should see an orange/red border from top to bottom.

Comment: That shows the top and bottom borders with the gradient, but the sides are still white.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100340/discussion-between-henrik-andersson-and-ironwaffleman).

Comment: @HenrikAndersson: If the gradient is iffy it won't work with CSS itself. As it is working with pure CSS and pure JS implementations, I firmly believe there is nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix such problem by adding `1 / 1 / 0 stretch` by myself to the inline-style so it looks like this:

```js
var borderImage = `linear-gradient(to right, #1A80AC 0%, #1A80AC ${position.x / 3}%,
#8798AD ${ position.x / 3 }%, #8798AD 100%) 1 / 1 / 0 stretch`
```